# Can I make a full blown website with just .NET MAUI?

Tags: maui, .net-maui

So websites are usually made with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and since .NET MAUI is built to be cross platform, does this mean I can make a website people can go to on their web browser purely with .NET MAUI instead of the standard HTML + CSS + JavaScript?

Comment: There are some answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68500882/can-you-develop-a-webpage-using-net-maui-and-blazor-and-target-the-web-ios-an

Comment: Note that I think cross-platform in the context of MAUI means runs on IOS, Windows, Mac, Android = mobile and desktop platforms running on different operating systems. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross-platform doesn't mean all platforms. Right now the supported platforms are Android, iOS, macOS and Windows. Tizen is also there, donated by Samsung.

In this case a platform is more an actual OS/device family. More on what .NET MAUI is exactly and how it works can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui).

There are similar frameworks that *do* offer a web target along with all the supported platforms by .NET MAUI. [Uno](https://platform.uno/) is a well-known one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you have any idea if .NET MAUI will support web targetting in the future?

Comment: We don't have anything on the roadmap, I think it's unlikely for the near future. My own personal take is also we shouldn't. Mobile and desktop are already worlds apart, but web and actual client apps are even further apart. While you can technically make it work, I always doubt if it will benefit the UX.

Comment: Well it could be used in a very productive way. Once I learn how to use .NET MAUI, if it ever supported web, I wouldn't just plop whatever app I made onto a website, I'd probably make a separate project for the website using MAUI. The benefit of a cross platform UI framework isn't just that you can put the same project everywhere, it's that you only need to know that one framework to build apps and such for all platforms. So in that sense, being able to use knowledge for app making to make a site would be amazing. Also JavaScript sucks so it would probably be more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

If you architect your app correctly into multiple layers you can share a large portion of web and mobile NonUI code. Example : business rules, sql/SQLite data access,

Take a look at clean architecture or look at what aspnetzero team did.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).